# Set Value of a Dynamically Generated DropDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown menu that gets automatically populated. I need to set its selected value to a certain option whose ID is being passed in. This code seems to work with dropdowns that were created on page load:

```
    $('select[id$=DropDown1] option').each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).val() == _PassedInValue) {
            $(this).parent().val($(this).val())
        }
    })
```

But, it doesn't seem to work with dynamically generated content. Is there something I am missing or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: You are using ID to lookup the select. You have to make sure that the ID for the newly generated select is not same as an existing one. jQuery selectors would select only the first one with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing one particular element (`DropDown1`). No two elements can have the same `id`. Change your code to apply to all dropdowns like this:

```
$('select option').each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).val() == _PassedInValue) {
        $(this).parent().val($(this).val())
    }
})
```

Comment: but I need to set the value for a certain dropdown, not all of them,

Comment: Okay, well the exact code you specified won't work because you are referring to only one drop down list. The fact that it's dynamically generated should not matter.

Comment: What do you call 'dynamic' then? I thought you just meant created by JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the replies. My code works and I found the issue. I was doing a trigger for change event before trying to select that value. And the change event involved an AJAX call. I didn't realize that it doesn't wait for the call to complete to start selecting the value. I placed the abovementioned code in the AJAX success method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rerun your page's onload function after your dynamic content is loaded. 
Look at the callback function from this document:
http://api.jquery.com/load/